# SharePoint 2010 search scopes: Hide lists, show only elements

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, scope

I have a SharePoint list. It is a custom list with items.

However when I search for a word from the title of an item, the item shows up aswell as the list itself. I want to hide the list and only want to show the items.

I tried it with search scopes. If I set a rule with the criteria "Author" and my username, it works fine. I can't seem to find the right attribute for the listitems. I tried contentclass = "STS_ListItem" but it won't work.

I tried all contentclasses from this link:

http://slalomdotcom.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/sharepoint-2010-search/

but none shows my results, only when I set up the Author criteria.

Anybody has an idea how I could solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Niels